# Nvidia OptiX GeometryGroup

Tags: cuda, nvidia, raytracing, optix

Hello I'm using Nvidia OptiX to create a RayTracer. 
I used the example Programs "sample0" and "tutorial" to set up a simple tracer.

In my C++ Code i set up Everything with:

```
this->buffer_height  = 512u;
this->buffer_width = 512u;
char path_to_ptx[512];
_context = _context->create();
_context->setRayTypeCount( 1 );
_context->setEntryPointCount( 1 );
_context->setStackSize( 4640 );
_context["radiance_ray_type"]->setUint( 0 );
_context["scene_epsilon"]->setFloat( 1.e-3f );
_context["result_buffer"]->set( _context->createBuffer( RT_BUFFER_OUTPUT, RT_FORMAT_FLOAT4, this->buffer_width, this->buffer_height) );

sprintf( path_to_ptx, "%s/%s", projectPath, "RayTracer_generated_draw_color.cu.ptx" );
_context->setRayGenerationProgram( 0, _context->createProgramFromPTXFile( path_to_ptx, "draw_solid_color" ) );
_context["draw_color"]->setFloat( 0.462f, 0.725f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
_context["eye"]->setFloat( 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f );

_context->setMissProgram( 0,  _context->createProgramFromPTXFile( path_to_ptx, "miss" ) );
_context["bg_color"]->setFloat( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

sprintf( path_to_ptx, "%s/%s", projectPath, "RayTracer_generated_box.cu.ptx" );
Program box_bounds = _context->createProgramFromPTXFile( path_to_ptx, "box_bounds" );
Program box_intersect = _context->createProgramFromPTXFile( path_to_ptx, "box_intersect" );

sprintf( path_to_ptx, "%s/%s", projectPath, "RayTracer_generated_draw_color.cu.ptx" );

// This block must be full there. It is not possible just to create a geometry and not attach a program to it this would lead the program to crash when _context->compile();
Geometry gbox = _context->createGeometry();
gbox->setPrimitiveCount( 1u );
gbox->setBoundingBoxProgram( box_bounds );
gbox->setIntersectionProgram( box_intersect );
gbox["boxmin"]->setFloat( -2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f );
gbox["boxmax"]->setFloat(  2.0f, 7.0f,  2.0f );

Material box_matl = _context->createMaterial();
Program box_ch = _context->createProgramFromPTXFile( path_to_ptx, "closest_hit_radiance0" );
box_matl->setClosestHitProgram( 0, box_ch );

GeometryInstance geomIns = _context->createGeometryInstance( /* gbox, &box_matl, &box_matl+1 */ );
geomIns->setGeometry( gbox );
geomIns->setMaterialCount( 1u );
geomIns->setMaterial( 0, box_matl );

GeometryGroup geomGrp = _context->createGeometryGroup();
geomGrp->setChildCount( 1u );
geomGrp->setChild( 0, geomIns );
geomGrp->setAcceleration( _context->createAcceleration("NoAccel","NoAccel") );
//_context["target"]->set( geomGrp );

_context->validate();
_context->compile();
_context->launch( 0, buffer_width, buffer_height );

this->imageData = _context["result_buffer"]->getBuffer()->map();
this->vboId = 0;
rtBufferGetGLBOId( _context["result_buffer"]->getBuffer()->get() , &this->vboId );

RTsize buffer_width_tmp, buffer_height_tmp;

rtBufferGetSize2D( _context["result_buffer"]->getBuffer()->get() , &buffer_width_tmp , &buffer_height_tmp );
this->width  = static_cast<GLsizei>(buffer_width_tmp);
this->height = static_cast<GLsizei>(buffer_height_tmp);
```

My .cu program looks like this:

```
#include <optix.h>
#include <optixu/optixu_math_namespace.h>
#include "commonStructs.h"

using namespace optix;


// Variables of Context

rtDeclareVariable( unsigned int, radiance_ray_type, , );
rtDeclareVariable( float, scene_epsilon, , );
rtDeclareVariable( rtObject, target, , );

rtBuffer<float4, 2> result_buffer;

// Variables of RayGenerationProgram
rtDeclareVariable( float3, eye, , );
rtDeclareVariable( float4, draw_color, , );

// Globals
rtDeclareVariable( PerRayData_radiance, prd_radiance, rtPayload, );
rtDeclareVariable( uint2, launch_index, rtLaunchIndex, );
rtDeclareVariable( uint2, launch_dim,   rtLaunchDim, );
rtDeclareVariable( float3, shading_normal,   attribute shading_normal, ); 


RT_PROGRAM void draw_solid_color()
{
    float2 d = make_float2(launch_index) / make_float2(launch_dim) * 2.f - 1.f;

float3 U,V,W;
U.x = 1.0; U.y = 0.0; U.z = 0.0;
V.x = 0.0; V.y = 1.0; V.z = 0.0;
W.x = 0.0; W.y = 0.0; W.z = -1.0;

// Calc the ray Direction
float3 ray_origin = eye;
float3 ray_direction = normalize( d.x*U + d.y*V + W );

// shoot the ray
optix::Ray ray(ray_origin, ray_direction, radiance_ray_type, scene_epsilon );

// Add ray Data
PerRayData_radiance prd;
prd.importance = 1.f;
prd.depth = 0;

//rtTrace(target, ray, prd);

//result_buffer[launch_index] = make_float4(prd.result.x, prd.result.y, prd.result.z, prd.result.w);

result_buffer[launch_index] = make_float4( abs(d.x), abs(d.y), 0.0f, 1.0f );


}

//
// Returns solid color for miss rays
//
rtDeclareVariable(float4, bg_color, , );
RT_PROGRAM void miss()
{
  prd_radiance.result = bg_color;
}


//
// Returns shading normal as the surface shading result
// 
RT_PROGRAM void closest_hit_radiance0()
{
    float3 res = normalize(rtTransformNormal(RT_OBJECT_TO_WORLD, shading_normal))*0.5f + 0.5f;
    float4 result;
    result.x = res.x;
    result.y = res.y;
    result.z = res.z;
    result.w = 1.0f;
    prd_radiance.result = result;
}
```

Like I posted it it works fine and a colored picture is visible, but you may have noticed that //_context["target"]->set( geomGrp ); in the c++ code. If I uncomment that the Program gets an exception in _context->compile();

The Box Program is the same as in all the examples.

Does anyone have an idea about what goes wrong when i want to set the target to the _context.

_context is of type Context like in #include .

Best Regards

Edit: found out more about the exception:

```
_context->compile();
```

is a shortcut for

```
checkError( rtContextCompile( m_context ) );
```

in optixx_namespace.h the returned result that is checked in checkError is a RT_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE .

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but I'll probably need to run the app. Could you mail us your full source code (or the full directions for how to morph one of our samples into your app)? Contact us at OptiX-Help@nvidia.com. If you send a .zip file, rename the extension to .zi_. David McAllister,
OptiX Manager

Comment: Hello David McAllister, thank you very much for you offer. Fortunatly I could fix the issue by myself. My Problem was I had an old install of CUDA 3.2 and CUDA 5.0 runing side by side.

Comment: rcpfuchs: make that an answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I could fix the issue by myself. My Problem was I had an old install of CUDA 3.2 and CUDA 5.0 running side by side.